# Sidebar on /unanswered inconsistent with result of clicking on those links

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, unanswered-questions, my-tags

If I go to [my tags in the unanswered section](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/?tab=my_tags), some links are shown to "unanswered tags" below my favorite tags.

[image]

If I follow any of these links, I get a search for the intersection of all my tags with that tag, which unsurprisingly gives zero results. These links give the impression that if I for example click on `ruby-on-rails`, I should get 1324 unanswered questions. This is inconsistent and somewhat confusing.

I'm not sure what the intended behavior of these links are, but this certainly looks strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these tag totals can't take you anywhere intuitive ("my tags" is an OR not an AND search) they'll stop showing up when you're on "my tags" starting with the next build.

The benefit is that these totals are also expensive to fetch, meaning that the page load should be much faster when uncached (most of the time for "my tags").