# Viewing "unanswered (my tags)" shows no items on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, filtering, question-lists

I have a lot of tags (including very common ones like `php`, `javascript`) but viewing the unanswered (my tags) on Stack Overflow in the Android app shows no items. Checking on the website shows this is incorrect.

Comment: This is a bug (and should be tagged as such), but I think it's on the backend, not in the app itself. What do you see on the desktop site under [Unanswered/my tags](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags)? In my case (on a different SE site), I get empty page despite the tags including some very common ones, with lots of unanswered questions. The app merely duplicates the same problem.

Comment: @youcancallmeAl You're right. What might be happening is they're  searching for items tthat have ALL your tags?

Comment: If they do, this is not by design (no question can have more than five tags, and there are six "my tags"). I reported the desktop bug at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12621 Do retag your question as a bug, or it won't be seen by devs.

Comment: @youcancallmeAl how do I do that?

Comment: Click [edit] under the question and change support to bug.

Comment: There's at least a confirmation that [searching using "my tags" is using OR relationship](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90697/241919). However, I couldn't repro this on 1.0.82 (beta), though I only have less than 10 favorite tags.